# Cannot push new branch to git server

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, vps, branching-and-merging

I am new with git and I am trying to set up a git repo in a VPS. I created a git repo in the server and then cloned it to my local PC. But when I try to create a new branch in my PC and push it to the server, even though it is pushed, but in the server when I try `git checkout mybranch` it shows `error: pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Here are the approaches I tried:

**APPROACH 1**

```
me@localpc:~/$ git clone ssh://me@server.domain/home/me/gittest
me@localpc:~/$ cd gittest
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git branch mybranch
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git checkout mybranch
Switched to branch 'mybranch'
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git >test
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git add -A
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git commit
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git push origin mybranch
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 1.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://me@server.domain/home/me/gittest
 * [new branch]      mybranch -> mybranch
......................
me@server:~/gittest$ git branch
* master
  mybranch
me@server:~/gittest$ git checkout mybranch
error: pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

**APPROACH 2** (using `git push -u`)

```
me@localpc:~/$ git clone ssh://me@server.domain/home/me/gittest
me@localpc:~/$ cd gittest
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git branch mybranch
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git checkout mybranch
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git >test
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git add -A
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git commit
me@localpc:~/gittest$ git push -u origin mybranch
......................
me@server:~/gittest$ git branch
* master
  mybranch
me@server:~/gittest$ git checkout mybranch
error: pathspec 'mybranch' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Both of these give the exact same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: For anyone (like me) wondering what `git >test` does, it redirectes the output of `git` command (the git help) to the file `test`.

Comment: Can you try to check the status of your branches with 'gitk --all' for example? What do you see in ~/gittest/.git/refs/heads?

Comment: In the 'approach 1', if that's really the sequence you do without anything else, it's kind of weird you are on mybranch before pushing but then you are on master when you do 'git branch'... ?

Comment: @mu無 Well, I intended to write only `>test` to create a blank file. But put `git` before it by mistake. But turned out ok I guess, hehe.

Comment: @Matthieu after the ....... that was the server console. Note `me@server`

Comment: Anyways, I fixed the problem. It was with `git init`. When I created the repo in the server, I used the command `git init`. But what I should have done was `git init --share`. Now I created a new repo with `--share` and it works as it should. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I fixed it. It was a problem at the beginning when I created the git repo in the server. I used the command `git init` to create the repo. That caused some permission problems and thus pushed branches could not be added properly. What I should have done was create the repo with `git init --share`. I created a new repo with this and now it seems to work perfectly.